# Buying electronics in Phnom Penh

Tags: electronic-items, shopping, cambodia, phnom-penh

I am going to phnom penh for a day or two in order to extend my visa. During the same trip I want to buy a micro sd  card for my phone, but I would rather not walk around the whole city to find a suitable shop.

So,  Is there a particular area or place in phnom penh with a cluster of shops selling electronics?

Comment: It might be the best to go to one of the larger malls such as the AEON mall to make sure you get proper merchandise.

Answer (score 2):

Either the [Sorya Mall](http://phnompenhshopping.com/shopping-centers/sorya-shopping-center/) or the [Aeon Mall](http://phnompenhshopping.com/shopping-centers/aeon-mall-phnom-penh/) have electronics shops that sell SD cards.